# Solving the following differential equation: $\frac{dN}{dt} = rN(1-N^2)$.

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Here, r is a positive constant and has initial condition N(0) = $N_0$, a constant.

My attempt:

$\frac{dN}{dt} = rN(1-N^2), \\
\frac{1}{N(1-N^2)} dN =  r dt, \\
(\frac{1}{N} - \frac{1}{2(1+N)} + \frac{1}{2(1-N)}) dN = rdt,\\
\log(N) - \log( \sqrt{(1+N)}) + \log(\sqrt{(1-N)}) = rt + c, \\
N - \sqrt{(1+N)} + \sqrt{(1-N)} = Ae^{rt}. $

I don't know where to go from here, or if I've messed up somewhere.

Comment: you want to combine the logarithms on the left side first, before exponentiating both sides.

Comment: $\log (x + y) \ne \log x + \log y$. Never!

Comment: Not $N - \sqrt{(1+N)} + \sqrt{(1-N)} = Ae^{rt}$ but : $$N \sqrt{(1+N)} \sqrt{(1-N)} = Ae^{rt}$$.

Comment: $e^{a \pm b} \not = e^a \pm e^b$ for the last line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your only mistake is going from this step...

> $$\log(N) - \log( \sqrt{(1+N)}) + \log(\sqrt{(1-N)}) = rt + c$$

...to the next step:

> $$N - \sqrt{(1+N)} + \sqrt{(1-N)} = Ae^{rt}$$

That is,

> $$\log(N) - \log( \sqrt{(1+N)}) + \log(\sqrt{(1-N)}) = rt + c \: \not
>  \Rightarrow \: N - \sqrt{(1+N)} + \sqrt{(1-N)} = Ae^{rt}$$

The right way should have been as follows:

$$\log(N) - \log( \sqrt{(1+N)}) + \log(\sqrt{(1-N)}) = rt + c \\
\log \left(N\cdot \sqrt{\frac{1-N}{1+N}}\right) = rt+c \\
N^2\cdot \left(\frac{1-N}{1+N}\right) = Ae^{2rt}$$ where $e^c=A$

Hope you can simplify the rest.

Comment: You dropped the square roots on the $(1-N)$ and $(1+N)$ factors in your second-to-last step.  Unfortunately, this makes it much harder to solve for $N(t)$ in closed form (you have to solve a cubic polynomial.)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I have made the proper corrections. Thanks for helping.